# Interpretar código Batch

Tags: batch

Soy nuevo en batch y no domino aún la sintaxis, quiero saber qué hace exactamente el siguiente bat que ejecuta una prueba de estrés a un servicio web.

```
if [%1] NEQ [] goto connumclientes
estresador 5 -jar estresador.jar Client
goto fin

:connumclientes
if [%2] NEQ [] goto connumsolicitudes
estresador %1 -jar estresador.jar Client
goto fin

:connumsolicitudes
if [%3] NEQ [] goto conrmihost
estresador %1 -jar estresador.jar Client %2
goto fin

:conrmihost
estresador %1 -jar estresador.jar Client %2 %3

:fin
```

¿Qué significan los números con el símbolo `%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Qué significan los números con el símbolo `%`?

Este símbolo permite acceder a los parámetros con los que inicies tus scripts, por ejemplo:

Archivo *test.bat*

```
echo %0
echo %1
echo %2
```

Al ejecutar el script desde la línea de comando:

```
X:\Test> .\test.bat parametro1 parametro2
"X:\Test\test.bat"
parametro1 
parametro2
```

Podemos observar que `%0` está reservado para recuperar la ruta completa del script en ejecución y los números consecutivos permitirán recuperar los siguientes parámetros que lances, es decir, el primer parámetro suministrado será `%1` el segundo será `%2` y así sucesivamente.

Más información al respecto de cómo manipular estos operadores: [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Partiendo de lo anterior podemos saber que el script va evaluando qué parámetros son suministrados para así saber qué comando debe ejecutar.

Para ello realiza una validación utilizando [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) en conjunto con el comparador [NEQ](https://ss64.com/nt/neq.html) para verificar si el parámetro fue enviado.

Si los 3 parámetros son suministrados se ejecutará la línea:

```
estresador %1 -jar estresador.jar Client %2 %3
```